# Why do my unit tests slow down after 26 upgrading to the latest version of jest

Tags: jestjs

When my jest version is 26,the unit test takes less than 5 seconds.
But when my jest version upgrade to the latest, unit tests slow down to more than 6s.

```
describe('index', () => {
  test('render', () => {
    const Monitor = require('./index').default;
    expect(typeof Monitor).toBe('function');
  });
});
```

I have not been able to find answers in the community

Comment: Can you setup reproducible example? I've tried the above and the results were different. For me using `^26` took **0.81s.** and on `^29` - only **0.53s.** (on the second runs, keep in mind that jest is using cache).